# Zip file unsupported php after donwload?

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to download a zip file on the server : as shown in picture
[image: Zip file]

so in my index.php file i wrote this code:

```
 $file_url = 'P_cra_v2.1.4.zip';  
 header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_url"); 
 header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
 header("Expires: 0"); 
 readfile("$file_url");
```

it downloads the file but any of my archiever are not able to open it as it says unsupported format.

What to do now?

Comment: How did you create the file P_cra_v2.1.4.zip ?

Comment: from my side it is running correctly, first check contains of zip file

Answer (score 0):

you should download winrar. some zip file are not supported by windows .they cannot extract the files because it is not supported by windws